# Storing large but simple array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, bigcommerce

Im trying to solve a problem for restricting the display of certain shipping methods on a web store and a little stumped on the best way to accomplish.

I have a semi large (43000 row) csv file that consists of 2 columns. Zip Code and Day in transit. At the "estimate shipping" stage of checkout I need to query this data via javascript. Im taking the shipping address zip code and using it to look up its corresponding days in transit and return that value for some further calculations. Normally I would load this into a database table but this store is on BigCommerce where no direct DB access is available so Im assuming this has to get done client side without setting up a remote DB.

What would be the best way for me to store that information if it had to be client side? My original idea was to create a giant array and store it in a JS file on the server that would be included when needed. HTML localstorage? Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: You may need to take a look at [_IndexedDB_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API), but is it really necessary to transfer the whole thing to the client? Is there some other way you could break up the data server side so you don't consume as much bandwidth/storage on the client?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you may be able to compress your data, and decompress at runtime using something like [zlib](https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js) - CSV data generally tends to compress very well, so if you're getting close to the localstorage limit, this might help.

Answer (score 1):

With localstorage you would get an 5mb per domain limit, I am not sure if that is enough to store the array you want.
Another way would be to convert that array to a .json file and use ajax/get in order to retreive it (GET will be cached so only the first time it will load the file from the server, then it will go much, much faster as it will load it from the client cache).